# JMeter - Capturing string using regex and replacing it with another string

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using JSON extractor to extract a large JSON file from a response and save it in a variable. I want to pass this variable in a request but I want to change 1 value in the JSON. This JSON has various customer details and I want to capture whatever the LoanAmount value is say "LoanAmount:50000" and replace it with a fixed value 1000.

This LoanAmount value appears multiple times in the JSON due to which I'm forced to use multiple JSON extractors to capture different parts of JSON file from the response and pass them separately in a request. I want to use a single JSON extractor to capture the whole JSON from the response and use a post processor to write a script that will use regex to capture whatever the LoanAmount value is and replace it with a fixed value of 1000. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question by providing response and request?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace values matching a regular expression in a JMeter Variable with another values using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the Groovy code like:

```
vars.put('replaced-values', vars.get('your-variable-here'.replaceAll(/("LoanAmount"\s*:\s*)\d+\s*,/, '\$11000')))
```

the `${replaced-values}` variable will have all occurrences of "LoanAmount" replaced with 1000.

More information: [Groovy Regular Expressions - The Definitive Guide (Part 1)](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/)

However it might be the case it's easier to get rid of the JSON Extractor completely and replace the attribute values in a JSON structure, it will be way more reliable and readable.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)